# Add a black border to columns in a heatmap and add space to separate them

Tags: r, heatmap

I want to add a black border to columns in a single-row heatmap, and add some space between the columns, like so:

[image]

I tried to add space between columns with `breaks` and `seq` and add a black border to each one but I could not.

```
library(graphics)
new <- matrix(c(1.3,3,4,6,1.2,1,0.8))
image(new, axes=F)
```

[image]

Comment: How set are you on this color palette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pheatmap package, there you can do:

```
new <- matrix(c(1.3,3,4,6,1.2,1,0.8))
pheatmap(t(new), cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F, border_color = "black", gaps_col = 1:6)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, both in base-R and in ggplot2. Your desired image looks a lot like a barplot. As there were bars with different values coloured in the same colour in your example, I've created some 'bins'. This was easier with all necessary data (for both solutions) in a dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(new=c(1.3,3,4,6,1.2,1,0.8),
                  x=1:nrow(new),
                  y=1)
dat$bin <- cut(dat$new,breaks=seq(0,6,by=1.5),include.lowest=T,
               labels=F)
```

In base R:

```
#create a color palette
mycols <- c("red","orange","yellow","white")

barplot(dat$y, col=mycols[dat$bin], axes=F)
```

In ggplot2:

```
p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x,y=y,fill=bin))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",col="black",size=2) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red",high="white")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank())
```